# phpexcel save modifying all the sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel file with around 40 sheets with some of the cells defined by formulas.
I read the contents of a single sheet and display on the UI. After user modifies the same i save it back to the excel using phpExcel save.
But when i save PHPExcel save modifies all the sheets with some junk values where ever there is a formula cell.

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {       
        //echo "row=".$row;
        if((sizeof($convertedArr)-1) > $row){
            $jsonRow = $convertedArr[$row];
            $type = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;                
            $colWrite = 0;              
            for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {       
                if($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() != 'xxxxx'){
                    //$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row,$jsonRow[$col]);
                    $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->setValueExplicit($jsonRow[$colWrite], $type);
                    $colWrite++;
                }
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    if(is_writable($siteName)){
        $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(FALSE);
        $objWriter->save($siteName);
    }else{
        echo "File is not Writable";
    }
```

How can i handle this situation.
How can PHPExcel just save the sheet in question and not all the sheets.
I am NOT even looping through all the sheets.

Also, one more problem is after save the formatting such as background color is gone!

Comment: Is it that the cells you are modifying contained formule before you save the new values to these cells?

Comment: Yes.Some of  the cells are based on formula.